# connect to DB java - the import java sql connection conflicts with a type defined in the same file

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I tried to connect to database using jdbc, but I have still error next to `import java.sql.Connection;`

> The import java sql connection conflicts with a type defined in the
>   same file

I have `mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` kept in Apache Tomcat Library.

Here is my code:

```
package demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Connect
 */
@WebServlet("/Connect")
public class Connection extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Connection() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            out.println("Can't load database driver");
            //e.printStackTrace();
            String strClassPath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");

            System.out.println("Classpath is " + strClassPath);
            return;
        }

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/webshop", "root", "root");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            out.println("Can't connect to database.");
            return;
        }

        out.println("Connected to database.");

        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {

        }
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because your class is also named as `Connection` and hence is creating the conflict while creating the object.

The line which must be creating the conflict is as follows:

```
Connection conn = null;
```

You can modify this as follows:

```
java.sql.Connection conn = null;
```

Or alternatively, rename your class to `DBConnection` or something else.

Comment: Bro! Thank you! I hate this kind of mistakes - driving you crazy :D

Comment: @Ernesto Your Welcome! :) Please accept the answer if it helps you solve the problem.

Comment: Of course! Hope it's done properly ;), best regards!